# TexMaker doesnot update the pdf file with WileyNJD-v5

Tags: pdftex, errors, pdf

I am preparing a document using the WileyNJD-v5 template. but when I compile it, it doesnot update the pdf file.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of an image.

Comment: check the log-file for errors.

Comment: There are no errors that appear in the log file but instead it shows a warning

Comment: LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.8.18) 2 SEP 2023 18:38
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./wileyNJDv5_AMA.tex
(wileyNJDv5_AMA.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
(WileyNJD-v5.cls
Document Class: WileyNJD-v5 2022/04/05 v5.0 Standard LaTeX document class for J
ournal
\job@temptoken=\toks17
(

Comment: don't show only a part. Show the complete log-file. Put in your question or somewhere on the web.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zv4rmVNb85v97HRLktivYn93mvxIW87bl1qrbTQwnBY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: there are multiple errors, and it makes no pdf: `(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)
### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 2253 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
(\end occurred when \iftrue on line 4752 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \iftrue on line 4740 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 2 was incomplete)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
..
1167 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
90i,1n,93p,361b,105s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
No pages of output.
`

Comment: well as @DavidCarlisle writes it ends with `No pages of output.`, and earlier `*** This file requires `listings.sty version 1.9.
*** You have a serious problem, so I'm exiting ...`.

Comment: So what to do in this case, please advise not that ....

Comment: you have not shown any code related to the error. Make a small complete document that fails in the same way and add it as a code block not an image, to your question

Comment: this is the code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/17cxbPa0p9hIcsk6lKB2KMLLaNgC6NZu5UiARPQQ6BMA/edit?usp=sharing

and this is the corresponding log file: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zv4rmVNb85v97HRLktivYn93mvxIW87bl1qrbTQwnBY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: remove the listings.sty in your document folder (and the other styles too) and then try again.

Comment: It worked perfectly but in the real code it gave me an error resulting me to omit the a line in the normalsize.sty ... Anyway, thanks a lot ... much appreciated ...